# Respond to User with CSS after failed authentication. (Passport)

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I have a site that allows users to login by clicking login which will popup a Bootstrap modal without redirecting the user. I see on many sites that if you fail to login you will remain on that route and all that will change is a message will appear notifying you of the failure to login. I would like to do this with passport local where after a failed authentication I can simply show some CSS while still having the Bootstrap modal up.

However, all that I can seem to do is show a req.flash and it seems that I have to redirect after a failed authentication or be shown an error.

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", 
{
    successRedirect: "/profile",
    failureRedirect: "/",
    failureFlash : true
})
);
```

Currently, this is all I can do. Is it possible to do it the way I've mentioned without redirecting? Passport documentation shows no sight of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can do whatever you want. From the official [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/):

`app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // req.user contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });`

"By default, if authentication fails, Passport will respond with a 401 Unauthorized status, and any additional route handlers will not be invoked. If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the req.user property will be set to the authenticated user."

So all you have to do is handle the 401 response in your client-side logic and then based on it show a message/CSS.

Comment: That's my problem, I don't know how to handle a 401 response client-side. Do you perhaps have a good guide you could recommend to me?

Comment: What are you using for a frontend? Or are you just serving a template directly from node?

Comment: I render ejs files for the front end.

Comment: I'm no ejs expert but this looks like it does something similar: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local